# HTML5 Canvas - For loop to place elements in grid

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grid, iteration

I'm in the process of building a simple level placement script in HTML5 canvas, and I'm having trouble actually placing each element down.  I've written a for loop that creates a grid, then I'm trying to create a new loop that iterates through each statement in my 'level' array to set positions for each image.  I haven't done a lot with Canvas before; as such, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in regards to placing these images; I've written something very similar to this in jQuery that works just fine - in fact, I copied and pasted the code to start with, but it doesn't seem to work in Canvas.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here's a snippet of the code; forgive the over-commenting, this is just a thing I do when I'm having trouble understanding why something doesn't work.  It's like an inline Rubber Duck.

```
var $levelArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, "blue", "blue"], 
  [0, "gray", 0, 0, 0], 
  ["blue", "blue", "green", 0, "blue"], 
  ["blue", 0, "yellow", 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, "gray", 0], 
  ["red", 0, 0, 0, 0]];

var border = 5, // set grid details
    spaceWidth = 80, 
    spaceAmount = 5;

    // create a tiled image
function makeTile(imageUrl, horizontalPosition, verticalPosition) {
  var tile = new Image();

  tile.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(tile, horizontalPosition, verticalPosition);
  }
  tile.src = imageUrl;
}

    // place the image tiles on the board
for (var i=0; i < ($levelArray.length - 1); i++) {
  var row = $levelArray[i]; // set each row's iterative position
  var rowHeight = 5;

  for (var j=0; j < row[j].length; j++) {
    var rowPosition = 5; // set the left margin of each element

    if (row[j] == 0) {
      rowPosition += (spaceWidth + 5); // if an element does not exist, jump forwards to the next space
    } else {
      //if one DOES exist, place an image in this space
      makeTile("http://lorempixel.com/80/80", rowPosition, rowHeight);
      rowPosition += (spaceWidth + 5); // then move to the next space
    };
  };
  rowHeight += (spaceWidth + 5); // once a row is complete, drop to the next row's positions
};
```

I have this in a codepen here: http://codepen.io/sarsparillo/pen/vNrWQG

I'm not sure why it's only loading one image at a time and putting it in the 0,0 space on my grid; using very similar code in jQuery (current code, which is pretty all over the place and sort of unclean, is here - http://codepen.io/sarsparillo/pen/GpdjYY) puts elements in the right place just fine.

More, when I added a console.log statement to those for loops, I honestly can't work out where the hell it's getting data from.  Like, one iteration gave me 'green green yellow' as the items in row[j], another 'blue gray blue' - does Canvas do something absolutely bizarre with iterating through an array?  I can't see how it could, seeing as this is just Javascript, but...?

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or any tips as to how I can resolve this?  In theory, it should just be adding the space width + the margin width to the start point of each 'square', so I'm not sure why it just... isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/4gr9apqm/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var border = 5, // set grid details
    spaceWidth = 80,
    spaceAmount = 5;

var $levelArray = [
    ["blue", 0, 0, "blue", "blue"],
    [0, "gray", 0, 0, 0],
    ["blue", "blue", "green", 0, "blue"],
    ["blue", 0, "yellow", 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, "gray", 0],
    ["red", 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

canvas.width = (spaceWidth * spaceAmount) + (5 * spaceAmount) + 5; // and here's the canvas size
canvas.height = (spaceWidth * spaceAmount) + (5 * spaceAmount) + 5;

// make a rounded corner square; using a sizing hack to make sure that strokes don't effect the full size of the item
function square(originX, originY, size, corner, fill) {
    var startFromX = originX + (corner / 2);
    var startFromY = originY + (corner / 2);
    var extentsX = startFromX + (size - corner);
    var extentsY = startFromY + (size - corner);
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = corner;
    context.fillStyle = "#513574";
    context.strokeStyle = fill;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(startFromX, startFromY);
    context.lineTo(startFromX, extentsY);
    context.lineTo(extentsX, extentsY);
    context.lineTo(extentsX, startFromY);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
}

// build a grid of said squares
function squareGrid(spacing, size, corner, color, amount) {
    for (var x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
        // build rows
        for (var y = 0; y < amount; y++) {
            // build column spacing in each row
            square(5 + (size * x) + (spacing * x), 5 + (size * y) + (spacing * y), size, corner, color);
            // build each square
        }
    };
};

// actually parse the arguments for said square
squareGrid(border, spaceWidth, (border * 2), "#f13574", spaceAmount);

// create a tiled image
function makeTile(tile, horizontalPosition, verticalPosition) {
    switch (tile) {
        case "blue":
            context.fillStyle = "#00F";
            context.fillRect(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, 80, 80);
            break;
        case "green":
            context.fillStyle = "#0F0";
            context.fillRect(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, 80, 80);
            break;
        case "red":
            context.fillStyle = "#F00";
            context.fillRect(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, 80, 80);
            break;
        case "gray":
            context.fillStyle = "#999";
            context.fillRect(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, 80, 80);
            break;
        case "yellow":
            context.fillStyle = "#FF0";
            context.fillRect(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, 80, 80);
            break;
    }
};

var gapHeight = 5;
var gapWidth = 5;

for (var y = 0; y < $levelArray.length - 1; y++) {
    var row = $levelArray[y];

    for (var x = 0; x < row.length; x++) {
        var newXPos = (gapWidth * (x + 1)) + (80 * x);
        var newYPos = (gapHeight * (y + 1)) + (80 * y)

        makeTile($levelArray[y][x], newXPos, newYPos);
    }
}
```

All I have changed is basically how you access your 2D array and the position calculation. Basically the first thing you access is your Y position, then from your Y position you look at all the blocks on that row. So we first find "in my case" `blue, 0, 0, blue, blue`. so all of these will have y position 0, and then it will go from 0, 80, 160 and etc. However because you wanted a gap in between the blocks you also have to multiple the gap by the x and y value at that time :)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not a huge fan of writing switch statements (I prefer keyed method lookups) but this looks like an excellent start for me; the final element will just have a text separator thrown in on top of this, as each space is listed like "blue left" "red down" etc.  Is there any reason you went with fillRect over using an image, other than ease of showing what's happening?  Basically, will loading an image into these spaces cause an issue that doesn't exist if you just go 'fillRect' or is the end result of placing images on the canvas pretty much the same as drawing a rectangle?

Comment: Using an image as long as it is 80 by 80 it will end up with the same result, I just used fillRect for ease :)